# Wie sagt man "hug bug" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, word-choice

> Jana mag die ganze Zeit ihren Freund Klaus umarmen.

Im Englischen würde man sagen, dass Jana den *Hug-Bug* hat. Da *hug bug* aber sehr [umgangssprachlich](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hug%20bug) ist, gibt es dafür keine direkte Übersetzung.

Welche Bezeichnung gibt es im Deutschen für jemanden, der andere Leute ständig umarmt?

Comment: Was is ein "Hug bug"? Ist es ein richtig insekt?

Comment: @omegacron Ein "bug" kann auch ein Fehler sein (auch "to be buggy"). Jana hat also den/einen "Umarmungsfehler"...

Comment: Ein "bug" kann auch eine leichte Krankheit sein. Jana hat die leichte Krankheit dass sie immer ihren Freund umarmen will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leute, die immer mit ihrem Partner zusammen sein möchten, kann man als **anhänglich** bezeichnen. Das beschreibt aber nicht das tatsächliche Umarmen.

Etwas abfälliger ist die Bezeichnung **Klammeraffe**, die den Körperkontakt mit einschließt.

> Jana ist ziemlich anhänglich. Ein richtiger Klammeraffe.

Comment: Noch abfälliger wäre "Jana ist eine Klette".

Comment: `klammeraffe` würde ich nicht zwingend als `mit körperkontakt` interpretieren. das ließe sich eher durch die wendung `Jana kann die finger nicht von Klaus lassen` oder das (umgangssprachliche) `kuschelmonster` ausdrücken.

Comment: @collapsar Kuschelmonster ist etwas weniger "offiziell", aber auch hübsch :)

Comment: Why not include it in your answer then??

Comment: @collapsar: Warum schreibst Du Klaus und Jana groß?

Comment: Aus dem Teil der Frage "für jemanden, der andere Leute ständig umarmt" ergibt sich für mich, dass sie nicht nur ihren Freund ständig umarmen will. Bei Kletten und Klammeraffen stehen Umarmungen nicht im Vordergrund - sie müssen gar nicht vorkommen.

Answer (score 2):

Ein eigenes Wort für dieses Verhalten gibt es im Deutschen nicht, aber man kann welche bilden:

- Umarmungsfimmel
- Umarmungstick (siehe Tick, nicht Stick)

Die von anderen genannten Klammeraffe und Klette bezeichnen anhängliche Menschen, die einem nicht von der Seite weichen, einen nicht allein lassen. Mit übertriebenem Hang zum Umarmen kann das zwar einhergehen, wird aber von niemandem so verstanden oder so ausgedrückt.

Answer (score 1):

Wie wärs mit einem

> Umarmungstick